# Jquery selector length returns 0

Tags: jquery

```
var app = app || {};

(function ($) {
    app.initialize = {
        init: function () {
            app.initialize.fullScreen();
        },
        fullScreen: function () {
            var scrHeight = $window.height();
            console.log($fullScreenEl.length);
            $fullScreenEl.css('height', scrHeight);
        }
    };

    app.documentOnReady = {
        init: function () {
            app.initialize.init();
        }
    };


    var $window = $(window),
        $fullScreenEl = $('.full-screen');

    $(document).ready(app.documentOnReady.init);

})(jQuery);
```

This is my code, when I run the code $fullScreenEl length return zero, I don't understand why. If move Document ready from (function($) {})(jQuery); then the $('.full-screen').lenght returns 1. Can someone suggest me something?

Comment: You're initializing `$fullScreenEl` outside of your `ready` handler.

Answer (score 2):

Change it this way:

```
(function ($) {
    app.initialize = {
        init: function () {
            app.initialize.fullScreen();
        },
        fullScreen: function () {

           var $window = $(window),
               $fullScreenEl = $('.full-screen');

            var scrHeight = $window.height();
            console.log($fullScreenEl.length);
            $fullScreenEl.css('height', scrHeight);
        }
    };

    app.documentOnReady = {
        init: function () {
            app.initialize.init();
        }
    };


    $(document).ready(app.documentOnReady.init);

})(jQuery);
```

You have to select the elements when the document is ready. Also, by moving the `$window` and `$fullScreenEl` inside of the `fullScreen` function the performance is better because accessing variables out of the scope is slower than accessing them in the same scope.